# Graph API failed to authenticate in Mobile Phone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am trying to integrate the `Graph Api` to our application to show **Logged in User Image**.

We have app registration with `Application Permissions` (Read directory data, Read all users' full profiles) and `Delegated Permissions` (Read directory data, View users' basic profile).

So the `adal library` is able to authenticate and display user image in Desktop but when i will try to access my application in mobile, the graph is not getting authenticated. (I did simulation in Chrome - Developer tools by changing the mobile device and tried in my phone as well).

I could see the error

> AADSTS50079: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must enroll in multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Trace ID: 2c99ca11-0c94-480c-8604-d9fd0ec40b00 Correlation ID: a3033da7-a994-437d-96e3-4b5612c73e45 Timestamp: 2018-08-21 19:10:21Z

I even enrolled in multi factor authentication in my mobile and tried to access the application but no luck.

Please guide me whether my app needs any more permissions? If so, please list out the permissions which i need to include to my app for graph api authentication in mobile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at this issue and see if it might have to do with your Reply URL/RedirectURI setup: https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/issues/50
2. You can try disabling MFA on your tenant to see if that overrides the issue.
3. Normally this issue is generated as a result of Conditional Access. The following document provides more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-conditional-access-developer. You may have applied Conditional Access policies onto resources and apps that require extra conditions to be met before granting authorization. This could be due to MFA policies or IP range restrictions.